# What books of Escrima patterns that detail each step are available?

Tags: recommendation, training, books, escrima

I know Escrima generally has minimal emphasis on forms, but that there are nevertheless some patterns associated with certain Escrima variants.

Many more popular/formalized martial arts have books available detailing each step in a kata for several skill levels, and I'm wondering what (if any) books are out there that do that for Escrima patterns.

I would prefer books that have line drawings of people in each stance for each move (or if there are photographs, good ones) with some notes on proper positioning at each step. Thanks!

Comment: What style of Escrima? I can think of some 50 different styles...

Comment: Good question-the problem is my teacher is using his own particular style. Here's a link to his description of it :http://www.defensormethod.com/ Obviously I'm not expecting any books to be available that follow his method, but I'm interested in reading about the styles that gave rise to it/that are closely related.

Comment: Then for doce pares I hear these are supposed to be good. http://www.imafit.com/ProShop.html Can't speak to them personally.

Comment: @stslavik Cool, thanks. You might want to make that an answer--I'm still going to hold off for a bit and see what more shows up, but so far that's the best lead.

Answer (score 4):

**A process cannot be understood by stopping it. Understanding must move with the flow of the process, must join it and flow with it.** -- Dune, Frank Herbert

I do not know of any books that do this, but you are better off watching Youtube videos, like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3w07cUh7z1Q), which describes heaven and earth. You're better off looking for 'heaven six' first, though. The key will be to look up some list of drills so you get the names, then look 'em up on Youtube.

Comment: I know youtube videos are helpful, and certainly I'll take a look, but sometimes you don't have access to the internet or you want annotations on what the pattern is doing. It's a good comment, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @RSid Youtube videos (or movies or books) are only useful if you understand the art, and understand it well. If you do not have a reference from which to draw, you will not learn anything, and, more likely, end up creating very big mistakes.

Comment: @stslavik ...yes. Which is why I practice at a dojo with a teacher and my classmates on a regular basis. I'm merely curious about what books are out there and interested in using one as a supplement.

Comment: @RSid Good to hear, but not everyone is the same; any advice that references back to media should be reviewed time and time again throughout your training. You'll have different viewpoints at different stages. Best of luck!